# MediaPlayer: buffer status for internet radio stream?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, buffering, internet-radio

I am playing internet radio streams using MediaPlayer. However buffering seems to take about 10 seconds for me each time I start playing a stream. Is there any way I can show:

1. The progress when starting to play? E.g. a progress bar in the GUI
2. The buffer status once playing? (e.g. to give a warning when buffer is running dry for some reason)

I tried using `setOnBufferingUpdateListener()` but as far as I can tell, it only works for streams where the duration is known. (So not applicable to internet radio, unless I'm wrong - it was not being fired)

Answer (score 1):

Implements MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener, overriding the method onInfo you have action to control the status of the MediaPlayer as follow:

```
@Override
public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer arg0, int what, int extra) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "MediaPlayer INFO code = " + what + " extra=" + extra);
    if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Start buffering...");

    } else if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "End buffering...");
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Start playing...");

    }
    return false;       
}
```

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html for other actions;)

Comment: From what I can tell, this again only applies to media where the duration is known. onInfo() is not being triggered for radio streams

Comment: I can't understand why you say this considering that I use the method that I posted inside the service for my radio application!!!!!! So why you think that???

Comment: It's weird, the only MediaPlayer callback that's getting called is `onPrepared()`. I'll look into it and will +1 you if it works. But I'd still like to know if there is any way of determining how much has been buffered (not just if it has begun or finished buffering)

Comment: I don't know why that is the only callBack getting called, I assure you that in my service both onInfo and onBufferingUpdate are called every time I start the stream from webRadio URL.